# Want to use urdu keyboard in my android app

Tags: android, keyboard

My question is that how can i use Urdu keyboard in my android app?
basically i am a beginner and using eclipse. i am making a book app in Urdu language. in which i'd like to add a search view through which user can search the contents in list view easily.
but the problem is that i have made the app in Urdu language so i have to use Urdu keyboard for searching.
so is there any easy way through which whenever user clicks on the search-bar Urdu keyboard appears to search ? 
i have tried to make custom keyboard but it is very difficult to make. and as per my research changing input language by force using java code is not recommended.

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Answer (score 4):

You have to make your own custom keyboard. It is not too difficult. You can follow the complete tutorial present at http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm.

### Summary:

You need to make customized layout of keyboard in URDU (You can use unicodes characters for urdu in your layout file http://tabish.freeshell.org/u-font/chart.html ) Layout will contain key tags for each key. Each key tag will have label in urdu and unique keycode of your choice. 
Then you need to implement `OnKeyboardActionListener` interface and override onKey method. In this method you need to search for the view in focus (if it is not an EditText then abort). Then you need to executes an action based on the actual key code (which in this case is appending the corresponding urdu character in EditText). Hope this will help you

Comment: thank u for explaining in a good way.. but i am facing a problem ..i am trying to understand the tutorial. when i change the key label and unicode (<Key android:codes="FE8D"    android:keyLabel="ا" />) in the code given in that tutorial and run the program. when i am clicking on this button which i made nothing shows up

Comment: Can you see button you made in URDU ? As mentioned earlier, you need to implement OnKeyboardActionListener interface and override onKey method. In this method, you will write code to modify EditText. Because when key is pressed, onKey handler is fired. Urdu character will not automatically go into EditText.

Comment: Accept this answer if you found this helpful

Comment: I have the same problem at hand, i have implemented the keycodes part, the problem remaining are the labels, cant seem to find and implement keylabels for URDU language, should i use drawables for the labels or is there any other way to show the URDU/Arabic labels

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following two websites that highlight your problem and have given a well explained tutorial, these are:

http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

this will help you to create a customized virtual keyboard after this all you have to do is replace the keycodes for your desires keycodes; the unicode are written in this website

http://unicode-table.com/en/#arabic

Remember you have to use the Dec Code 1605 not the hex U+005. I still dont know how to implement the labels part, so if you find that out, please mention in the comments

P.S, dont forget to mark this as an Answer